# Windows Media Player's media sharing is stopping

Tags: media-player, vmware, sharing, wmp, dlna

Windows Media Player is stopping media sharing after a certain time.

Environment

- I am running a Windows 7 64Bit with Media Player 12 on vmware server 2.0.2
- WMP libraries are pointing on network folders

I am logged in on the guest machine (Windows 7) and the Media Player is sharing it's content. So, I can access where ever I am my media files.

**The issue**

As soon as the vmware window is closed and I am not longer accessing any media files it takes a certain time until the media file sharing will stop. That WMP is disappearing as an entry under "Other libraries" in any other Media Players.

When I reopen the vmware window I have to log me on again on the guest machine. After that the media sharing is working again.

**So, is there a way to keep the sharing while the vmware window is closed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was thinking about that for a longer time and then I posted the question. After that I continued on that and I really found the problem.

The reason for stopping media sharing was caused by the power profile of Windows 7. I switched from Balanced to High Performance so that the media sharing will not be stop on idle.